# how do I open for view a google sheet using google apps script

Tags: google-sheets

This is my code so far. It runs but does nothing.

```
function Quiz1Load()  
    {
    var ss =     SpreadsheetApp.openById("1JJ6AtvvSqoX0qK6OMQgGizhwjGVxnyWmYqX_STAW0t4");
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheet);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you can open a file 'programmatically' with google apps script (on the server, e.g. for modification of the file through the script), you can not open it 'physically' (on the client side).